# Repeat <div> as a header every page while printing

Tags: html, css

I'm in a trouble right now. I wanna repeat div element every page while printing.

Without using . How can I do it?

Example

Page1:

[div]

```
Text header
```

[/div]

[div]

```
Content page 1
```

[/div]

Page2:

[div]

```
Text header
```

[/div]

[div]

```
Content page 2
```

[/div]

Comment: Without using what?

Comment: While printing what?

Comment: @ciekals11 I'm sorry but when I type <table> element, then It's not appear.

Comment: @codeRdevelopR printing html page, dear.